# How To Import Binary Dump File To SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to import a dump file which is in binary format to SQL Server using sqlcmd command. After running the import command, I am getting this error, `Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62` I'm suspecting that it is because the file is in binary format. Is there a way to directly import binary dump file to SQL Server? I tried using the -u flag but I'm getting the same error.

Sorry, forgot to mention, I am using SQL Server 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04

Command: sqlcmd -S localhost -d TestDB -U SA -u -i /home/user1/Downloads/myspecialpresentforyou

Error Message: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Server user1, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'TAPE'.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual command you used - See [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Hi, I updated my post.

Comment: Post the SQL command(s) that are in your `-i` input file.  The -i parameter _Identifies the file that contains a batch of SQL statements or stored procedures. _  You should also post the `create table` DDL for the table you're importing into.

Comment: Make sure you're using the proper `sqlcmd` switches - See the [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017) documentation.

Comment: Show full error message, not start of it only...

Comment: What do you want to do? Restore a database? You cannot specify -i with binary file, it specifies sql SCRIPT, i.e. file containing sql commands.

Comment: @sepupic Yes, I would like to restore a database.

Comment: To restore a database you should use RESTORE command

Comment: @sepupic Thanks. I'm currently playing around with it. I can still restore binary file dump using restore command, right?

Comment: Yes you can. I posted the answer showing how to restore using sqlcmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of tango ward is that he tries to pass `full backup file`e as a `script` file to `sqlcmd`.
I understood it as he wrote the error is

> Could not find stored procedure 'TAPE'.

The first bytes of a backup file even if it's disk file are 'TAPE':

[image]

To make a simplest `restore` from the `bak` file without restoring it to another database and moving the files you still can use sqlcmd, but you should pass your file as a `backup file location`, i.e. use this command:

```
restore database MyDB from disk = '/home/user1/Downloads/myspecialpresentforyou'
```

Here is simple example of doing it in `sqlcmd`:

- First I launch `sqlcmd` (without parameters I'll connect to my
  default instance with win authentication, but you should use your
  `sa` user and password as you did)
- Once launched `sqlcmd` you'll see `1>` it's a prompt to enter your
  command, now enter there RESTORE...(the whole command, see above) and
  after entering it (press ENTER) you'll see 2>
- Now enter GO to send your command

Here is how I restored my database `abc` from full backup `Z:\Anna\backups\default\abc_full.bak`

[image]

If you restore to **another** database you should first know logical file names using `restore filelistonly` and then move the files to new destination.

If it's your case you'd better use SSMS to see these files as sqlcmd output can be combersome if your db has many files.

Here the example in SSMS:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran the code stated above but I am getting an error message:

Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Server user1, Line 1
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'TestDB' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server user1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: This means that you already have TestDB database and it's not this database backup. Why do you want to restore it over existing database?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. The TestDB is empty. I would just like to put this dump file in this empty TestDB to see the structure of it and proceed with data migration to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Basically, this dump file is from a client and I am tasked to perform data migration from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Sorry, I am reading this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-restore-database?view=sql-server-linux-2017 I tried following the procedures on this site, however I am still getting the same error message. Any advice?

Comment: Hey, I am sooo happy I am able to restore it. My mistake is that I have created a database before running the RESTORE command. I didn't have to. The command will create the database and move the ldf and mdf files to the directory of /var/opt/mssql/data. I got a message saying that the RESTORE DATABASE SUCCESSFULLY. Now I want to know if there's a GUI like SSMS version in Ubuntu?

Comment: I found out I can use SQL Operation Studio in Linux. I think I'm all set. Now, I will research what python wrapper I could use for migration. In PostgreSQL I am using pyscopg2. Thanks a lot for your help @sepupic.